# How to resolve `Illegal instruction` error while running docker run command?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have build a docker image inside the vagrant machine and also from TRAVIS linux enviroment and then i have pushed this image to Docker hub and pulled into Softlayer machine.

After i pulled the image, i ran docker run command like below

`docker run -i -t rameshthoomu/openpeer /bash/bin` then when i run

root@23495a2ed7a8:/go/src/github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer# /go/bin/obc-peer peer command i am getting below error message.

`Illegal instruction`..

It's working file when i build and run the same image inside the vagrant environment. Also, if i create an image inside the softlayer machine, i could run the image and can proceed further.

I don't have any clue why i am getting this error message. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The command is `/bin/bash/` not `/bash/bin`.

Try the following instead:

`docker run -i -t rameshthoomu/openpeer /bin/bash`

Comment: sorry. its typo.. i have used `/bin/bash`